# Rails & TinyTDS - connecting to local database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, tiny-tds

On our Ruby on Rails applications, we use tinytds to connect to Azure SqlServer databases. Sample configuration would be as below (and in general, it all works fine)

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver 
  host: mytestsite.database.windows.net
  mode: DBLIB 
  port: 1433 
  database: mytestdb
  username: myusername
  password: mypassword
  azure: true
```

At the moment, working remotely, I find this very slow. So I would like to take a local copy (as I would do with my .Net applications) and attach to that.
Finding connecting to **(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB** a problem with tinyTDS.

Would anyone have done this before?

Comment: Are you connecting to named SQL Server instance? If so, it listen on different port.

Comment: Its not a port issue, have no issue connecting with .net applications locally